# How to simplify using array destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6, eslint

`eslint` keeps showing me a `prefer-restructuring` error. However, I'm don't really know how array destructuring works and would love some help.

These are the two lines returning an error:

```js
word.results.inCategory = word.results.inCategory[0];

// and:

word.results = word.results.filter(
 (res) =>
  Object.keys(res).includes('partOfSpeech') &&
  Object.keys(res).includes('inCategory')
)[0];
```

Again, I'm not very knowledgable in this area, so any help on how to fix/simplify this specifically would be appreciated!

[image: eslint error]

---

**EDIT:** Here is an example object for reference:

```js
{
  word: 'midrash',
  results: [{
    definition: '(Judaism) an ancient commentary on part of the Hebrew scriptures that is based on Jewish methods of interpretation and attached to the biblical text',
    partOfSpeech: 'noun',
    inCategory: ['judaism'],
    typeOf: [ 'comment', 'commentary' ]
  },
  { 
    definition: 'something',
    partOfSpeech: 'something',
  }],
  syllables: { count: 2, list: [ 'mid', 'rash' ] },
  pronunciation: { all: "'mɪdrɑʃ" },
  frequency: 1.82
}
```

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: You cannot use **destructuring** to redefine properties of an object which means that you'll have to use two statements, something like `const { results: { inCategory: [ category ] } } = word; word.results.inCategory = category;`

Comment: FYI you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you just need the first encounter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of `inCategory` you should use the destructuring assignment as follow:

```js
const obj = {
  word: 'midrash',
  results: {
    definition: '(Judaism) an ancient commentary on part of the Hebrew scriptures that is based on Jewish methods of interpretation and attached to the biblical text',
    partOfSpeech: 'noun',
    inCategory: 'judaism',
    typeOf: [ 'comment', 'commentary' ]
  },
  syllables: { count: 2, list: [ 'mid', 'rash' ] },
  pronunciation: { all: "'mɪdrɑʃ" },
  frequency: 1.82
}

let {results: {inCategory: category}} = obj;

//Now you can assign the category to word.results.inCategory
console.log(category);
```

For the filter approach, I suggest using the function `Array.prototype.find`

```
word.results = word.results.find(
 (res) =>
  Object.keys(res).includes('partOfSpeech') &&
  Object.keys(res).includes('inCategory')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, both of those worked great! Out of curiosity, is there any difference between `.find()` and `.filter()` in this particular situation?

Comment: @Lioness100 as you want to get the first index regardless of the number of objects, you can get the first match using the function `find`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already sure that your data structure is correct and both `word.results.inCategory` and `word.results` are arrays then this is how you do it:

```
const { results:{ inCategory: [inCategory] }} = word;
word.results.inCategory = inCategory;

// and:

const [results] = word.results.filter(
 (res) =>
  Object.keys(res).includes('partOfSpeech') &&
  Object.keys(res).includes('inCategory')
);

word.results = results;
```

Of course in the second destructing when you filter you can just use find that allows you directly set the `word.results` without destructing:

```
word.results = word.results.find(
 (res) =>
  Object.keys(res).includes('partOfSpeech') &&
  Object.keys(res).includes('inCategory')
);
```